# JSF Converter <p:selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu

I can't create converter class in jsf for

```
<p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{t.idmehsul.adi}" />
 </p:column>

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step create a converter in jsf:

1. Create a converter class by implementing `javax.faces.convert.Converter` interface.
2. Implement `getAsObject()` and `getAsString()` methods of above interface.
3. Use Annotation `@FacesConvertor` to assign a unique id to the custom convertor.

You can refer at [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm) to understand more how to create a converter in JSF.